# What is the pythonic or most efficient way to increase an iteration over combinations?

Tags: python, loops

I have a numpy array: NxM

Let's say:

```
input_data = np.random.rand(10,5)
```

I want to create a new array, where the new array is every possible difference between the columns of input_data, which will give you an array of size: (10, 10)

My code so far is:

```
def get_data_differences(read_data):
    '''Finds every possible differences between the columns of the read_data
    read_data: NxM variable where M are the features
    returns diff_data, and NxR variables
    R is the number of every possible combination of 2 columns

    '''
    if len(read_data.shape) != 2:
        print 'The data format is not consistent'
    data_rows, data_columns = read_data.shape
    data_difference = np.zeros((data_rows, 1))
    for combination_pair in itertools.combinations(read_data.T, 2):
    #iterate over every possible pairing of columns (hence the .T)
        minuend_, substraend_ = combination_pair
        difference_ = minuend_ - substraend_
        data_difference = np.append(data_difference, difference_[:, None], axis = 1)
    data_difference = np.delete(data_difference, 0, 1)
    return data_difference
```

I find not so efficient to delete the original array of zeros I created.

If you have any better suggestions, it would be great

Comment: your doc string can be one long multiline string as long as it starts and ends with `'''`.  You don't have to open and close every line with them.  Just one to start and one to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not index multiple columns at the same time?

```
np.diff(read_data[:, list(combinations(range(read_data.shape[1]), 2))])[..., 0]
```

Comment: Because.... it's still a long way before I wrap my head around all the flexibility in Python, btw, what do the 3 points in the index do, is the first time I've seen them

Comment: @Leonpalafox it's mostly the power of NumPy indexing.  Try breaking the expression down to see what it does and experiment indexing with different shape objects.